# How can I simplify these char array?

Tags: c++

Hello I Have to loop this char array but the last argument changes by one everytime. The last number is supposed to be 100 and since i cant write 100 times the same line of argument i wanted to see if there is a simpler way of writing it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

char command[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 1";
char command2[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 2";
char command3[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 3";
char command4[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 4";
char command5[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 5";
char command6[100]= "ousbsim -r io PORTB 6";
```

and so on..

Comment: Lookup, convert integer to string, and how to concatenate strings.  Then you could build however many string you want using a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an array of strings, and then use a loop to populate the strings.

For example, try something like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char commands[100][36];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::sprintf(commands[i], "ousbsim -r io PORTB %d", i+1);
    }

    // use commands[0]..commands[99] as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Or, using C++'s `std::string` instead of C-style `char[]` arrays:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string commands[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        commands[i] = "ousbsim -r io PORTB " + std::to_string(i+1);

        /* alternatively:
        #include <sstream>
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "ousbsim -r io PORTB " << i+1;
        commands[i] = oss.str();
        */

        /* alternatively:
        #include <format>
        commands[i] = std::format("ousbsim -r io PORTB {}", i+1);
        */
    }

    // use commands[0]..commands[99] as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it says that its not compatible with "const char*"

Comment: @Pierre It says WHAT is not compatible with WHAT? You did not explain what you want to use the command strings for. If you are trying to pass a C++ string to an API expecting a C string (`std::system()`, perhaps?), you can use the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method.  In which case, I would probably just get rid of the `commands[]` array altogether and use a single `string` instead, eg: `for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) { std::string command = "ousbsim -r io PORTB " + std::to_string(i); system(command.c_str()); }`

Comment: This is the error:
argument of type "std::string *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" I want to use it to run it thought a pipe code that changes one value in a txt file

Comment: @Pierre that is still not helpful information. It sounds like you are trying to pass the entire array to something that is expecting individual strings instead. WHAT are you passing the string array to EXACTLY? Please update your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with. Though, I would suggest posting a whole new question, since your original question has been answered as asked, and now you are asking for something different. Per StackOverflow guidelines, please limit posts to 1 question each.